# how to detect lines of code with regex in VIM

Tags: regex, linux, vim

I have so many println("") in my codes .. I know it is messy ... I want to put comment for each of the println("");

how to do that in VIM ? I mean I want to do that on multiple files.

Also if possible, can it detect whether the lines has // already or not ... if the lines has been commented .. I don't want to add new //

Comment: Do you only want to comment out lines that contain `println("")` *exactly* or any line that contains `println("whatever")`?

Comment: println("[ whatever.....] ");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append a `//comment` to all uncommented `println(...)` calls on their own lines:

```
:%s/^\(\s*println(.*);\)\s*$/\1\/\/comment/gc
```

To comment out all the uncommented `println(...)` calls on their own lines

```
:%s/^\(\s*println(.*);\)\s*$/\/\/\1/gc
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the :global command:

```
:g|println|normal I//
```

:g executes the command (here :normal I//) on all the lines when the first argument (here println) matches.

Also if you want to do this on all opened buffers, use the :bufdo command:

```
:bufdo g|println|normal I//
```

And to only do this on uncommented lines Amarghosh's regexp is perfect:

```
:bufdo g|\s*println(.*);|normal I//
```